# Seagate Back Up Plus Slim: exFat Still Unknown even if exfat-fuse, exfat-utils, exfat-dkms was Installed on Ubuntu 18.04.4 even Upgraded to 20.04

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, exfat

I have just buy new Portable Hard Drive, Seagate Backup Plus Slim 2TB.
That HD just work fine in Windows 7 on my wife's laptop. But detected as Unknown partition in my Ubuntu 18.04.4 (from Disks Manager), and Showing some Warning Message on GParted. I Attach the screenshots.

I was installed `exfat-fuse`, `exfat-utils`, `exfat-dkms` just like the others that have the same problem, but didn't work for me.
Please help me. I need my space of my New HD ASAP.

[Unknown Partition on Disks Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOOBX.png)

[GParted Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xu1C.png)

UPDATE:

I have read this [Arter97 exFat](https://github.com/arter97/exfat-linux#-merging-the-drivers-to-existing-linux-kernel-source), but i still don't understand in the 
"`Merging the drivers to existing Linux kernel source`" Step. Please help me.

UPDATE 2:

I Have Upgrade to 20.04, hopefully my problem will gone. But, still Happened.

[THIS IS WHEN I MOUNT IN WINDOWS 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAPrB.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked (on Windows) what type of file system is in place? Could it be NTFS?

Comment: Yes. It's exFat

Comment: You shouldn’t have to follow the process under Merging the drivers to existing Linux kernel source. If you have followed the instructions in the Ubuntu PPA section it should just work. It might be useful to see the output of lsblk. This will show if and where the drive is mounted. If you have a system backup you might want to try updating to 20.04. This has a kernel that I understand supports exFAT without the need for any other drivers

Comment: @PonJar I've upgraded to 20.04, and the problem still not gone. ;(

Comment: Have you uninstalled the old exFAT packages? Does a standard USB key work? What is the output of lsblk with the drive attached?

Comment: Are you sure it’s exFAT? I’ve seen more than one reference to it being formatted in NTFS. Perhaps you just need the NTFS driver

Comment: @PonJar : I Have Uninstall exfat-* then reboot my laptop. Then install exfat-* again. But still detected as Unknown Partition by Gnome Disks.

This is the result of `lsblk` :
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
....
sda      8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 277,8G  0 part /
└─sda2   8:2    0  20,3G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1,8T  0 part

sdb is that axfat drive.

Comment: @PonJar I have attach the screen of drive when i plug in to Windows 7. No Problem except No Label.

Comment: Finally I was forced to make a dual boot with Windows 7. But that's not what I expected, because Windows could not detect ubuntu's Ext4 partition. It makes it more complicated.